# Printing reports with APEX Office Print on a master detail page

Tags: master-detail

I have created a new blank page with: interactive grid, items and button print with dynamic action for APEX Office Print plugin with SQL Code and it is printing my reports the way I wanted.

But, I want to do the same exactly thing inside my master detail page. When I enter my detail form I want to have a button "print" with the same action for printing that report. I have done the same thing (like on the "blank page") on my master detail form (added new button print with dynamic action and SQL Code and connected it with my primary key) but it is not working, it is printing blank reports.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Apex Office Print is not an oracle product, it is developed and supported by https://www.apexofficeprint.com/

Comment: Hi Mateja, can you let me know which version of APEX and AOP you are using?  I'm happy to look into it for you. Most likely it's easiest if you create a quick example on apex.oracle.com and give me access to it. Thanks, Dimitri

Comment: APEX - 20.1.0.00.13    AOP - v20.1.3

Comment: @DimitriGielis did you have a look?

Comment: Hi Mateja, 

I updated your app and it seems to work now on page 7. The reason you got an empty document was because the id wasn't in session state. You can add your bind in session state by specifying them in Affected Elements of the AOP DA. I saw you use Session State Protection on the id you needed to submit, as you might get an AJAX checksum error, I added another item with the same value (P7_AOP_ID) which gets submitted. 

Seems to work now :) 

Note: as I didn't have access to the app, I made the page public for now

Comment: Woow thank you! I have applied that to my original app and it's working :) Do you understand set value Dynamic actions in Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another item with the same value (P_ID) which gets submitted. Then add new button print with dynamic action and SQL Code and connected it with that new item you have created.